# How to query json server from remote

Tags: javascript, json, ubuntu-server

I try to install json server on vps ubuntu server, but im unable to query json remotely, I find documentation just to query from localhost.

I installed node.js:

> sudo apt-get install nodejs
>
> sudo apt-get install npm

I installed json_server:

> npm install -g json-server

Starting json with a db for testing

> json-server --watch db.json

trying to set an host instead localhost

> json-server -H mysite.com

I can't the result

May i ask an help to query from remote json server on vps ubuntu server?
Thanks

Comment: Should you not do `json-server -H 'mysite.com' -w db.json`? As [according to their documentation](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#cli-usage)

Comment: Thanks man! i got it!